# AJAX + Flask update server request when filling form

Tags: ajax, flask

On the Flask website there's a tutorial on how to use AJAX and this an example to display the sums of two numbers.

This is the python app
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

```
# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/_add_numbers')
def add_numbers():
    a = request.args.get('a', 0, type=int)
    b = request.args.get('b', 0, type=int)
    return jsonify(result=a + b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=int("80"),
        debug=True
    )
```

This is the HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
  <script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
      $('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/_add_numbers', {
          a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
          b: $('input[name="b"]').val()
        }, function(data) {
          $("#result").text(data.result);
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-muted">How To Manage JSON Requests</h3>
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <div>
      <p>
    <input type="text" size="5" name="a"> +
    <input type="text" size="5" name="b"> =
    <span id="result">?</span>
    <p><a href="javascript:void();" id="calculate">calculate server side</a>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I see that with this example one is able to send a request to the server every time one clicks on the link, however, I would like to know if it's possible to skip this step and get the request overtime the text inputted by the user changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  It's wasteful of resources, but you could change

`$('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {` to

`$('input[name="a"]').change(function() {`

And do the same for input `b`

---

## Edit:

And, to test AS YOU TYPE:

`$('input[name="a"]').on('input',function(e){`

or:

`$('input[name="a"]').keyup(function(e){`

Comment: thanks, it looks like it's working, but only when I hit enter or I click out of the input box :/. I wish I could call the server as I'm typing in the form.

Comment: use a throttle function here to keep the number of calls down...\